# Unity: Why isn't TrailRenderer.GetPosition() working? "'TrailRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'GetPosition'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject player;
private TrailRenderer tr;
private Vector3 v;

void Start () {

    tr = player.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
}

void Update () {
    v = tr.GetPosition(0);
}
```

Whenever I try to use the GetPosition() method for the Trail Renderer, I get the error: "'TrailRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'GetPosition' and no extension method 'GetPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'TrailRenderer' could be found".

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: what is the name of your script? did you name it TrailRenderer by chance?

Comment: Well, the [method exists](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer.GetPosition.html) and it looks like you're calling it with the correct arguments. Are you using the most recent version of Unity? EDIT: I think ryemoss might be on the right track. Make sure you don't have any other scripts named `TrailRenderer`; you may be trying to use those rather than the built-in Unity class.

Comment: No, the script in this case was named "Example" and none of the other scripts in my project are named TrailRenderer. However, my version of unity is at 5.5.1 so maybe I have to update it?? I could give it a try.

Comment: Is autodestruct enabled in your trail renderer inspector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TrailRenderer.GetPosition` function was added in *Unity 5.6* but you are using *Unity 5.5*. This is why you cannot use it. You need to update your Unity version in order to use this function.

Comment: Yes, I just updated now and it is working. Thanks guys.